# javafx doesn't show html files with some images

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I tried several tests to remove my problem. I tried jdk 1.9.xx too, but I didn't resolve it.
I have a browser that comes from oracle WebViewSample.java (javafx).
With html files with some images, my browser not shows the images.
Now, I use jdk 1.8.0_152.
The html file is (hello_old_4.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Hello Java-Buddy!</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--
<img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MzAwWDMwMA==/z/b1gAAOSwX3FaKAcV/$_57.PNG">
-->
<!--
    <img src="https://imagesvc-eu1.ebay.com/imageser/v1/image/segment?site-id=101&placementlocid=IT_THU_digest_T1L&co=1&user-id=42991772536">
-->
<img src="https://imagesvc-eu1.ebay.com/imageser/v1/image/segment?site-id=101&placementlocid=IT_THU_digest_T1L&co=1&user-id=42991772536&imgWidth=1&imgHeight=1&run-date=20171207030000&placement-type=segment&TemplateId=3ca68d66-259b-482d-b412-17a8b55a665f&TrackingCode=16TE64304_T_ALL&TemplateVersion=152"
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use, into html file, the instruction:

```
<img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MzAwWDMwMA==/z/b1gAAOSwX3FaKAcV/$_57.PNG">
```

My browser shows the image.
If I use, into html file, the instruction:

```
<img src="https://imagesvc-eu1.ebay.com/imageser/v1/image/segment?site-id=101&placementlocid=IT_THU_digest_T1L&co=1&user-id=42991772536&imgWidth=1&imgHeight=1&run-date=20171207030000&placement-type=segment&TemplateId=3ca68d66-259b-482d-b412-17a8b55a665f&TrackingCode=16TE64304_T_ALL&TemplateVersion=152">
```

My browser doesn't show the image.
I tried with others programs, but I have the same situation.
If I put, one at a time, the two images into firefox web bar o others browser,
the image is always displayed.
The java program sample  that has the some problem of my browser is:

```
package javafx_webview2;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
*
* @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
*/
public class JavaFX_Browser2 extends Application {

private Scene scene;
MyBrowser myBrowser;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");

    myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
    scene = new Scene(myBrowser, 640, 480);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    String css = this.getClass().getResource("BrowserToolbar.css").toExternalForm(); 
    scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
    primaryStage.show();
}

class MyBrowser extends Region{

    final String hellohtml = "hello.html";

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();


    public MyBrowser(){

        URL urlHello = getClass().getResource("hello_old_4.html");
        webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());

        getChildren().add(webView);
    }
}
}
```

The style sheet used is(BrowserToolbar.css):

```
.browser{
    -fx-background-color: #666970;
}
.browser-toolbar .hyperlink, .browser-toolbar .button, .browser-toolbar{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.browser-toolbar{
    -fx-base: #505359;
    -fx-background: #505359;
    -fx-shadow-highlight-color: transparent;
    -fx-spacing: 5;
    -fx-padding: 4 4 4 4;        
}
```

All the files that I have to put are in the same directory, in my case is: javafx_webview2.
I hope an answer to my problem, thanks.

Comment: https://imagesvc-eu1.ebay.com/imageser/v1/image/segment?site-id=101&placementlocid=IT_THU_digest_T1L&co=1&user-id=42991772536 is 1x1 pixel in size . . . there is nothing to see.

Comment: change script instrution of the html file:
from this: <img src="https://imagesvc-eu1.ebay.com/imageser/v1/image/segment?site-id=101&placementlocid=IT_THU_digest_T1L&co=1&user-id=42991772536">.
to this: <img src="https://imagesvc-eu1.ebay.com/imageser/v1/image/segment?site-id=101&placementlocid=IT_THU_digest_T1L&co=1&user-id=42991772536&imgWidth=1&imgHeight=1&run-date=20171207030000&placement-type=segment&TemplateId=3ca68d66-259b-482d-b412-17a8b55a665f&TrackingCode=16TE64304_T_ALL&TemplateVersion=152">.
sorry for my wrong.

Comment: I changed my html file on the image istructions, for clearity. sorry for my wrong.